# Delete record from DB with possible childrens

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

In DB i have only one table:
**navigation** (InnoDB)
[image]

Is it possible configure this table to:
If i delete where id == 1, all id 1 (Root Item) subs will be deleted automatically?

**UPDATE**

I try to recreate table:

```
CREATE TABLE `navigation` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` VARCHAR(32),
`url` VARCHAR(32),
`position` int(10),
`parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `type` (`parent_id`)
CONSTRAINT `??????` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
  REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

But What value need in line 9?

Comment: Here table already exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ?????? should be the foreign key you are creating (your_key_name) between the tables.  'parent_id' in navigation is linked to 'id' in types.  When the navigation table has an update or delete done, the delete/update is cascaded to the types table.

```
CONSTRAINT `navigate2types` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
  REFERENCES `types` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Remember that you need to use the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Now when run query: /* SQL Error (1005): Can't create table 'cms.navigation' (errno: 150)

Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed */